# My session variables are not holding their values until I refresh the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am loading an asp.net page into a browser and I am experiecing issues with session state.

In my `Page_Init`, I am doing this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If validPlayer() Then
        FillSession()
        'try to refresh the page
        Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, False)
    End If

    If Session("playerID") = 194483 Then
        Response.Redirect("~/launcher/PortalLogin.aspx?err=You do not have permissions to access this game.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillSession()
    Session("gameID") = Request.QueryString("gameID").ToString
    Session("playerID") = Request.QueryString("playerID").ToString
End Sub
```

I am using a test player when developing.

So I pass in a gameID and playerID(194483) via the URL.

The problem is, when it hits, `FillSession`, then checks if `Session("playerID") = 194483`, when debugging, the session is empty and I get the `You do not have permissions to access this game.` message.

It's like it hasn't had time to fill the session yet.

However, if I refresh the page, it works fine.

So I tried adding this line after I call `FillSession()` to refresh the page:

```
Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, False)
```

But that just ends up putting the browser in an endless loop.

Is there a way to get the page to refresh silently so that the session values are there?

Thanks!

Comment: how is validplayer populated?

Comment: @Jeremy oops Right now it just returns `true` no matter what due to my testing.

Comment: so that's a good place to start troubleshooting! where is the code which sets this variable?

Comment: Better to use page load event - check if IsPostBack = False for the first code that runs.